# __NSCFString nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint: this occur in ios 10 only

Tags: swift, ios10

I have made one application which is working good in ios 11 but when i try to run this in ios 10. It suddenly start crashing and give this error.

```
-[__NSCFType nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000199cc0
```

I try to trash issue but don't know why this is occur. In exception breakpoint it show me below place

```
 func showFullScreenLoading(inView objView:UIView?,withMsg strMsg:String = "Please wait!!!")
    {
        guard let view = objView else
        {
            return
        }

        let objParentView = UIView.init()
        objParentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        objParentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        objParentView.tag = -123456
        view.addSubview(objParentView)

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[objParentView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["objParentView":objParentView])) //At this line exception error
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[objParentView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["objParentView":objParentView]))
}
```

> Calling of the function

```
 func apiCalled(_ objOperation:TagApiOperation){

    self.currentRequest = objHomeViewModel.apiCallHome(objOperation: objOperation, withDictData: [:], withLoaderBlock: { (isStart) in
        if isStart{
            SINGLETON.showFullScreenLoading(inView: self.view) // I called this function in view did load and there will be no background thread are there
        }else{
            SINGLETON.hideFullScreenLoading(inView: self.view)
        }
    }) { (isStatus, strMsg, arrBanner) in

     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i got the solution this issue occur because of safe area. safe area available from ios 11 so if you have ios 10 supported application then disable the safe area.

Comment: This is great, it fixed a difficult issue for me! Other than making two xib, one with safe area and one without, do you know any way to disable the safe are in an xib depending on iOS version?

Comment: @AndrewSmith No i didnot know about this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix the issue is by setting deployment target **"iOS 10 and Later"**

1. Open xib in the Xcode
2. From tom menu select **View -> Inspectors -> File**
3. Select **"Builds for"** as **"iOS 10 and Later"** in **"Interface Builder Document"** section